# Deleting array from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, dynamic

I am new to C++ and programming in general and have a group assignment for class. We all worked on different parts and I have to make the 'delete' part of the program. I have to delete the specific variable a user ask (if it's in the array) than shift the array to the right. After it does what it needs to do it 'shrinks' the array by half.

I think I can do the shrink easy, but I am having weird issues with my code giving me weird memory addresses it looks like.

Here is my part of my code :)

```
else if (option == 'd') {
        cout << "Delete element:" << endl; //Ask user which array position to delete//
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

            cout << arr[i]; //print out which array index we have///
            cout << endl;
            int pos; //starts new variable for position///
            cin >> pos;
            if (pos >= 1 && pos <= size) //As long as position is greater than 1 and less than size it loops//
            {
                for (i = pos; i <= size; i++)
                {
                    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
                }
                arr[size] = 0;
                cout << "Elements now:" << endl;
                for
                    (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
                    cout << arr[i] << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Element doesn't exist" << endl; //Tells user it doesn't exist if the position doesn't exist//
```

So if I add the element such as like 2, it shows me that 2 is in the array. I enter 2 into the input, and it gives me

`Elements now:
2
-33686019
0`

I am sorry if this is confusing! I am trying to learn myself. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Is `size` the number of elements in your array, or the top index? You do know that the top index is one less than the number of elements?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude size is the number of elements which is 2.

Comment: @PKPython What is the type of `arr`? "Normal" C++ arrays start at index `0` and end at index `size-1`, so in that case your `for` loop must terminate at `i < size`, not `i <= size`. Play through it with `size=2`: `i` will become `0`, `1` and `2` - that's three elements you are accessing of an array with only two elements. You do this in several other places, so take a look at each array access and ask yourself "can this index I access ever be larger than `size-1`?". Using a debugger will also help you understand what happens at each step in the program - it will really help a lot.

Comment: collegial programming without council how to implement data storage and segregate code into functional parts results in a nightmare-inducing code. Maybe professor wants to illustrate that for students. Or may be he doesn't care or just wants them to struggle with language  as an educational effort. Anyway problem is that this is incomplete code, it's not clear what we work with. Only clear that separation of concerns is not used at all.

Comment: Also consider using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of raw C++ arrays. They will usually show a diagnostic message when your array indexes get out of bounds, where as accessing a raw C++ array out of bounds just results in _undefined bahaviour_ (google that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume, that:

1. `arr` is a fixed size array.
2. `size` is actually variable that stores count of currently "used" elements of array.
3. your input policy accepts indexes starting with 1, so `arr[0]` corresponds to input `pos = 1`.

There are a few problems with this part:

```
            for (i = pos; i <= size; i++)
            {
                arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
            }
            arr[size] = 0;
```

First, if size is equal to array's size, you get undefined behavior, because arr[size]
doesn't exist. That's where you get strange values, they are result of trying to read outside of array bounds. It's a undefined behaviour.

Second after shifting array you have to decrements size if you do not want to print "unused" elements.

```
for (int i = pos-1; ++i < size;  ) 
// array should stop when i < size, but increment happens at beginning of loop. 
{
     arr[i-1] = arr[i];
}
arr[size-1] = 0;  // set last element to zero
size--;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by confusion over array indexes. In C++ arrays start at 0 so the valid indexes for an array of size n are 0,1,...,n - 1. There are good reasons for this and once you become an experienced programmer it becomes second nature but annoyingly users insist on counting from 1 and so for users the valid indexes of an array of size n are 1,2,...,n.

The best way to avoid confusion is to convert user indexes to C++ indexes immediately on input (or immediately before output). So that way most of your code is using the C++ indexing scheme (reasonable enough since it's a C++ program).

Applying that to the code above you get

```
int pos;
cin >> pos;
--pos; // convert from user indexes to C++ indexes
if (pos >= 0 && pos < size) // C++ indexes
{
    for (i = pos + 1; i < size; i++) // C++ indexes
    {
        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    }
    --size; // array is now smaller
    cout << "Elements now:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // C++ indexes
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Element doesn't exist" << endl;
```

The bit I'm confused about in your code is the `count` variable. I've no idea what that is, the way you use it makes no sense to me so I've ignored it, but you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing the `arr` declaration